# cURL for loop variable

Tags: curl

Is there a way to write a for loop with a URL and change the URL each time? I want to append &skip=***XX*** with different numbers to skip, is there a way to write it so that the variable is in the URL?

Comment: give us your input and wanted output

Comment: I still dont know too much about cURL coding, but if my url is https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.openfda.pharm_class_epc:"nonsteroidal+anti-inflammatory+drug"&limit=100&skip=XX is there a way to loop it so that I can get a bunch of data from a loop rather than manually?

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Please [edit] your question to add extra information, it is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments. Anyway, what you're asking for is trivial but to help you we need specific examples since the details depend on the URL format.

Comment: @terdon I think I figured most of it out using the command prompt (I am working from Win 7):

 FOR /L %i IN (0,100,500) DO echo curl "api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?&search=receivedate:\[20040101+TO+20150101\]&limit=100&skip=%i"

Right now that will echo the 5 different url's, but I am having trouble with curl (6) errors telling me that they cannot resolve the host. Any idea on how to get past it? I've tried everything I found on forums.

Comment: Sorry but this site is about Linux and Unix systems, Windows questions are very much off topic here.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, easily. For example:

```
for num in 100 200 300; do curl "http://foo.bar&skip=$num" ; done
```

Or, you can have the list of numbers in a file (one per line) and use a while loop:

```
while read num;  do curl "http://foo.bar&skip=$num" ; done < nums.txt
```

Or even generate them using `seq`:

```
seq 100 100 300 | while read num;  do curl "http://foo.bar&skip=$num" ; done
```